# Tello Connection Issue: Exception: Command 'command' was unsuccessful for 4 tries. Latest response: 'command'

Tags: python, udp, connection

I've created this simple tello code:

```
from djitellopy import Tello
tello = Tello()

tello.connect()
```

However, every time I try to run the code, the drone light is yellow. The desktop can identify and connect tello's wifi, but when the code run to tello.connect(), it will show below error:

Exception: Command 'command' was unsuccessful for 4 tries. Latest response: 'command'

This happens only in one of my desktop cannot connect to tello, my phone and laptop can connect to tello and run the code successfully. Who can give me some solutions? Thks!

I tried re-install the conda environment; reinstall the djitellopy package,  but all failed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```py
tello.connect(False)
```

so the full fixed code would be

```py
from djitellopy import Tello
tello = Tello()

tello.connect(False)
```

Hope that helps.